# What should i do if in a linear combination i have 3 scalars but only 2 solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra

Take for example this one : $(2,3)=X(2,1)+B(-1,1)+Z(1,2)$ the system has only 2 solutions for 3 scalars, how could i solve this?

Comment: Have you heard of linear dependence?

Comment: Look at the null space, and find a particular solution.

Comment: @John yes but haven't studied it yet, am i supposed to know it to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still learning the basics, then putting things in vector form is probably not the best idea. Instead, write them out as separate equations:

$$\begin{align}2x - b + z &= 2\\x + b +2z &= 3\end{align}$$

Note that you can add the two equations together to eliminate the $b$:
$$3x + 3z = 5$$
But now you only have one equation left. If you try to combine it with the others, you'll just insert $b$ back in as an unknown. The best you can do now is to solve for one of the variables in terms of the other:

$$z = -x + \frac 53$$

That is, I can pick $x$ freely. But the equation then tells me what the corresponding value for $z$ is. You can also solve of the the original equations for $b$. For example:
$$b = 3 - x - 2z$$ and substitute the expression for $z$:
$$b = 3 - x - 2(-x + \frac 53) = x - \frac 13$$
Thus the value picked for $x$ also tells you the corresponding value of $b$.

Any triple arrived at in this fashion will solve your original equation. For example, I just pick $x = 0$, which gives $b = -\frac 13$ and $z = \frac 53$. If we plug those into the original equations:
$$2(0) - \left(-\frac 13\right) + \left(\frac 53\right) = \frac 63 = 2$$
and $$(0) +\left(-\frac 13\right) + 2\left(\frac 53\right) =\frac 93 = 3$$
If instead we start with $x = 1$, then $$b = z = \frac 23$$ so we get
$$2(1) - \left(\frac 23\right) + \left(\frac 23\right) = 2$$
and $$(1) +\left(\frac 23\right) + 2\left(\frac 23\right) =1 + \frac 63 = 3$$

Regardless of the value of $x$ chosen you get another solution. As a general rule, if you have $n$ equations involving $k$ unknowns with $k < n$, the best you can do is use the $k$ equations to express $k$ of the unknowns as functions of the other $n-k$ (sometimes even this isn't possible, because some of the equations may be implied by the others, so really you have fewer than $k$ equations that you can use; and sometimes the equations contradict each other, meaning no solution is possible). Those remaining variables can take on infinitely many values, so the system of equations will have infinitely many solutions.

If $k = n$, then you can eliminate all the variables but one from the final equation, giving you a unique solution (for linear systems - nonlinear systems usually have a finite number of solutions). If $k > n$, then either some of the equations will imply the others, or some will contradict the others.